# ag-grid @version v17.1.1 Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using ag grid 17.0.1 version and its working fine in local development. But after prod  build i am testing in my uat environment. i am getting - 
Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
I debug the code after adding source-map. gridCore.js is throwing the error. its not even rendering my grid in UI.
I know dev and prod build are different. What's changing after prod build and why is it working in dev not prod.

```
var GridCore = (function () {
    function GridCore(loggerFactory) {
        this.destroyFunctions = [];
        this.logger = loggerFactory.create('GridCore'); // loggerFactory is undefined which is causing the problem 
    }
```

Comment: Whats's your Angular Version?

Comment: Angular version is 8.2.13

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the issue,  as per Ag-Grid Compatibility chart, Ag-Grid version should be in between 18-23 for Angular Version 7-9+.

Source: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/#compatibility